# In-line C# for BizTalk Scripting Functoid

Tags: c#, xml, biztalk, biztalk-2013

For the XML below, how can I use in-line C# in a scripting functoid to get the value of type where the element = 'SAON'?
For info, this is comes from a record within my source schema, the record contains encoded XML which I first of all convert to an XML document.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LocationXML>
      <Location>
         <Element>PAON</Element>
         <type>a</type>
      </Location>
      <Location>
         <Element>SAON</Element>
         <type>b</type>
      </Location>
</LocationXML>
```

In-line C#:  This comes from an app I built previously, not been tested in the map as yet but I suspect it's not a million miles away.

```
string s = NewValueXml;

 XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
 x.LoadXml("<root>" + s + "</root>");
return x.InnerText;
```

Comment: Can you please post the inline c# that is converting/returning the xml document? Thanks.

Comment: original post upated

Comment: Can there be multiple instances of a Location that equals SAON or only one occurrence?

Comment: Will only be the one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, in the scripting functoid that you use to convert the `string` into an `xmldocument`, I would do this and return a `string` then map it to your destination node. Hopefully I understood your question this time...

```
public string XMLConvertAndReturnType(string param1)
{
     string returnType = ""; //or String.Empty
     XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
     x.LoadXml("<root>" + param1 + "</root>");
     returnType = x.SelectSingleNode("//Location[Element = 'SAON']/type/text()").Value.ToString();
     return returnType; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I get what you're saying but what I'll have is encoded xml being turned into an XmlDocument via a scripting functoid, so this scripting functoid spits out an xml message for me to deal with so I can't really map the elements as parameters.